# Telegram Bot - permission levels for commands

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I'm new in Telegram Bot. There is way to setup permission level for only some commands?

I mean, instead of only "Admin" and "User" levels, have a "User+" role that has access to extra commands in the bot chat than stardard Users.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.